# Oracle Connect By top/bottom hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

How can I get the top and bottom of a hierarchy using connect by, I have a table that stores transition between ids(ID-> REPLACE_ID), I'm interested in getting the latest id starting from any id.

```
--drop table test_connect_by;
create table test_connect_by(ID number, REPLACE_ID NUMBER);
insert into test_connect_by values(1,2);
insert into test_connect_by values(2,3);
insert into test_connect_by values(3,4);

insert into test_connect_by values(51,52);
insert into test_connect_by values(52,53);
insert into test_connect_by values(53,54);
insert into test_connect_by values(55,55);

SELECT id,replace_id, level
   FROM test_connect_by
   START WITH ID in (1,51)
   CONNECT BY PRIOR replace_id = id;
```

I'm interested in getting the transitions from 1-4 and 51-54, alternatively I can start with 2 and get 2-4. Is there anything I can group by to identify group that start with 1 and the group that start with 51 ?

Comment: Do you want to have only two strings: first: 1-4 second: 51-54 based on your input?

Comment: I need 2 columns:ID and LATEST_ID, starting with any id

Comment: @Rodriguez If there is a possibility that `replace_id` can be less than `id` then take a look at [Lennart answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25156763/997660)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one(more straightforward) of the approaches you can simply find lowest `id` and highest `replace_id` grouping by `connect_by_root()` value, if `replace_id` is always guaranteed to be greater than `id`, otherwise see [Lennart answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25156763/997660):

```
select min(id)         as begins
     , max(replace_id) as ends
  from test_connect_by
 start with id in (1, 51)
 connect by id = prior replace_id
 group by connect_by_root(id)
```

Result:

```
    BEGINS       ENDS
---------- ----------
         1          4
        51         54
```

Comment: Are you sure that replace_id > id?

Comment: @Lennart no that is not the case

Comment: @Nicholas I was missing the connect_by_root functionality, I didn't know how to group it, by what key :) Thanks!

Comment: If replace_id > id is not guaranteed then the answer will be wrong after `insert into test_connect_by values(4,0)`

Comment: You want get the last "value" in the chain, you will get the greatest. I.e you would still get (1,4), as I interpret the question the answer after this insert should be (1,0).

Comment: @Lennart Yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

Untested, so there might be some errors in there:

```
select id, replace_id 
from (
    SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT id as id, replace_id
         , row_number() over (partition by CONNECT_BY_ROOT id order by level desc) as rn
    FROM test_connect_by
    START WITH ID in (1,51)
    CONNECT BY PRIOR replace_id = id
) as T 
where rn = 1
```

Comment: @Nicholas, apparently we edited the post at the same time, I hope I got the essence of your edit included when I updated the query.